# Are there any hints about the content of the Hollyhock letter?

Tags: bojack-horseman

After Hollyhock, BoJack's half-sister finds out that he got a teenage girl drunk and then just dumped her at the hospital with alcohol poisoning, she starts to avoid him. Finally, after the disastrous, second TV interview she sends him a letter, one which Bojack really dreads to open.

When he finally does,

> Bojack is absolutely shattered and starts drinking again.

We never know (in-universe), what was the content of this letter, but has there been any hint given by producers/directors/writers etc?

Of course, we can roughly guess that she tells him

> to never see her again

or something similar, but the letter seems to be quite long and it would be great to know any details.